# ASP.NET Custom SQLite DeleteExpiredSessions()

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

The SQLiteSessionStateStoreProvider.DeleteExpiredSessions() is not running automatically on the IIS 7 at any interval. I understand that if my database for session state storage were on inProc, it would be managed automatically at runtime, and if it were on an actual SQL database, there would be a script that would be ran by the SQL agent on an interval to clear expired sessions. However, my issue is that despite having the function defined in the library supplied here: https://github.com/micahlmartin/SQLiteSessionStateStore (renamed to DeleteExpiredSessions() and made public) I am unsure how to have the IIS server call this function, or if I need to implement a scheduled function of my own on the back-end to call this. On the IIS server the session state is set to custom, at 20 minute intervals expiration. It is set to cookie mode, as is the same settings on the web.config for the server. The database is currently holding data from the past 7 days for session states, and I am unsure how to interact with it from the back-end, or if I am missing some service or implementation. Anyone with experience running a custom SessionStateProvider via SQLite through a C# MVC should know how to resolve this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this from your Global.asax:

It runs DeleteExpiredSessions() after about 10 minutes. In the interim it checks every 0.25 seconds to see if the application is shutting down. If it is shutting down then it stops.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static Task SessionCleanup { get; private set; } = null;
    public static bool ApplicationEnding { get; private set; }

    public static void PeriodicallyRunSesssionCleanup()
    {
        int cleanupInterval = 600000;//10 minutes
        int sleepInterval = 250;// 1/4 second
        while(!ApplicationEnding && cleanupInterval > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
            cleanupInterval -= sleepInterval;
        }
        if(!ApplicationEnding)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Place your code that cleans up sessions here to have it run every 10 minutes.");
            SessionCleanup = new Task(PeriodicallyRunSesssionCleanup);
            SessionCleanup.Start();
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SessionCleanup = new Task(PeriodicallyRunSesssionCleanup);
        SessionCleanup.Start();
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationEnding = true;
        if (SessionCleanup != null) SessionCleanup.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: The name "DeleteExpiredSessions()" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: It wouldn't,this is the method you mentioned supplied by https://github.com/micahlmartin/SQLiteSessionStateStore (renamed to DeleteExpiredSessions() and made public), which calls a cleanup procedure in the database. 

There are several examples online of session cleanup procedures, even on msdn. If you need help creating one, or implementing a data layer that is better handled in another question. Let me know if you have a related question and I'll jump on to help.

Comment: It would call no method to cleanup any database. This does not reference the instance of the provider, only the static library.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. I've updated the answer for additional clarity.

Comment: Cant reference a static library without referring to the instance generated as the provider. I found the solution was the library did it's own purge on a timer, based on the timeout defined in web.config. Set this to 20 minutes and now it is purging every 20 minutes, multiplied this value in the library by 3 now sessions last 20 minutes, and purges happen hourly. No code needed in the MVC, all in the library with one setting in web.config, thanks for the help though.